# My unity IEnumerator method not seems to be work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, yield, coroutine, yield-return

I have some code: 
Why Debug.Log inside the IEnumerator method not display anything?
And why my method isn`t working?

```
void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G))
        {
            Debug.Log(true);
            MoveInsideTheShape(speedy);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator MoveInsideTheShape(float speed)
    {
        speed = 1 / speed;
        float totalLenght = cam.orthographicSize * 2;
        float iterationLenght = totalLenght / speed;

        Debug.Log(cam.orthographicSize); // does not work
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect us to do when you only tell us "it doesn't work"?

Comment: You don't even return anything from this function so how do you expect it to work?

Comment: Do you receive any compiler errors? The method in question looks incomplete.

Comment: The `IEnumerator` is never being iterated. I think you have to use some sort of helper method in Unity?

Comment: Why do you have it as `IEnumerator`? Rather use a simply `void` here since there is no looping going on here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though you are missing a return statement from the `MoveInsideTheShape` method, adding it would still not solve your issue.

IEnumerator methods have to be iterated using the `StartCoroutine` helper method.

Here's a tested working code.

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G))
    {
        Debug.Log(true);
        StartCoroutine(MoveInsideTheShape(speedy));
    }
}

public IEnumerator MoveInsideTheShape(float speed)
{
    speed = 1 / speed;
    float totalLenght = cam.orthographicSize * 2;
    float iterationLenght = totalLenght / speed;

    Debug.Log(cam.orthographicSize);

    yield return null;
}
```

Helpful links:

- https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html
- https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html

Comment: @SnowyOwl It is very questionable though if this should be an `IEnumerator`/Coroutine then because as it is it could simply be a normal `void` method call running once from top to bottom ....

Comment: Don't know the full context of the code, but yes, in the specific example it could simply be a `void` return type method.